# 404 whilst refreshing react routes with laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack

Working with a react laravel based project, and I was following a tutorial in order to see how both interact with each other. The application consist of making a simple `CRUD Application`, with three routes :

- `/` Home route
- `/create` create a project route
- `/{id}` single project route

I am having an issue debugging an error related to the `third route`, to elaborate `localhost:8000/7` will bring the project with `id 7` and it works fin upon creating the project, or upon accessing it from `/`, But if I want to access it via typing the full url like `localhost:8000/7`, I am getting `404 not found`.

[image]

I am missing something, and I can't figure it out ??

`App.js`:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import ProjectsList from "./ProjectsList";
import NewProject from './NewProjects';
import SingleProject from "./SingleProject";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducers/index';
const store = createStore(reducer)
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                    <Header />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={ProjectsList} />
                            <Route path="/create" component={NewProject} />
                            <Route path="/:id" component={SingleProject} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

web.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;



Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
Route::post('projects', 'ProjectController@store');
Route::get('projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show');
Route::put('projects/{project}', 'ProjectController@markAsCompleted');
Route::post('tasks', 'TaskController@store');
Route::put('tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@markAsCompleted');
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');
```

Comment: Can you post your route configuration?

Comment: Yes... needed routes file... `routes/web.php`

Comment: @Jerodev I am relying heavily on react router dom for navigation inside my app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The catchall route that is used for your React application should be in the `web.php` routes.

```
Route::view('{path?}', 'app');
```

You added this in your `api.php` routes. However, these routes are prefixed with `/api/`. That is why it won't work on refresh.

Keep in mind though that you should load the catch all route always as the last route. Otherwise other routes might no longer work.

Comment: so if I continue working with web.php for routes, and return `View` with `wantsJson()`, I guess everything should work right ?